# Escaping value of XML attribute with xsltproc

Tags: xml, xslt

With **xsltproc** (XSLT 1.0) I'm trying to escape (" -> to \") content from xsl-value @name attribute.

XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="int:signature">
    "name":"<xsl:value-of select="@name" mode="text"/>",
    ....
```

Original XML:

```
<signature name="My &quot;case&quot;" />
```

Output:

```
 "name":"My "case"",
```

which breaks resulting JSON

I've tried using *str:replace* with no success.
No success with *disable-output-escaping="yes"* either.

Any hint?

--

xsltproc -V

Using libxml 20706, libxslt 10126 and libexslt 815

Comment: Please add an example with your expected output (and perhaps input): shout this be `"name":"xxxxx"` or `\"name":\"xxxxx\"`. Or should the content of `@name` be changed?

Comment: I've improved explanation a bit. Yes, content of @name should be changed (to be escaped).

Comment: One possibility with xslt 1.0 would be to use recursive template calls to escape the quotes. But would it not be sufficient  to change the outward quot to an apostrophe. `"name":`My "case"´,` (This should be valid jason)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your need to escape something like this will help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space  elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match ="signature">
        <xsl:variable name="escape">
            <xsl:call-template name="escape_quot">
                <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="@name"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        "name":"<xsl:value-of select="$escape" />",
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="escape_quot">
        <xsl:param name="replace"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($replace,'&quot;')">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($replace,'&quot;')"/>
                <!-- escape quot-->
                <xsl:text>\"</xsl:text> 
                <xsl:call-template name="escape_quot">
                    <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="substring-after($replace,'&quot;')"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$replace"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will generate the wonted output.

```
 "name":"My \"case\"",
```

**Update:**
But would it not be sufficient to change the outward quot to an apostrophe.

with:

```
 "name":'<xsl:value-of select="@name" />',
```

to get:

```
  "name":'My "case"',
```

(This should be valid JSON)

Comment: If I changed to "name":'..' I imagine that I'd need to care about ' instead of " I guess, since some parameter values might contain that character.

Answer (score 0):

This works with XPath 2.0

```
"name":"<xsl:value-of select='fn:replace(@name, """", "\\""")' />"
```

xsltproc doesn't support Xpath 2.0 as far as I know, but maybe the EXSLT extensions provide the same functionality

Comment: With xsltproc: `"name":"<xsl:value-of select='str:replace(@name, """", "\\""")' />",` I get this error: `XPath error : Invalid expression
str:replace(@name, """", "\\""")
                     ^
compilation error: file interproscan.xsl line 132 element value-of
xsl:value-of : could not compile select expression 'str:replace(@name, """", "\\""")'`